# How to convert TMM RNA-seq file (generated by edgeR) to list of differentially expressed genes

Tags: r, rna-seq

I have a TMM (trimmed mean of M values) file of whole RNA sequencing (generated by edgeR package) with two groups (group A with 27 samples and group B with 18 samples). Each samples is in one column and each gene is in one row and all of the columns have header. This file include the list of the genes (in one column) plus values for each gene in each sample. Using this file in R, I want to get the list of differentially expressed genes in group B compared to group A and with correction for multiple testing with Benjamini-Hochberg method (FDR <0.05). The output file should have log fold change, p value and adjusted p value for each of the differentially expressed genes.

I'm wondering can anyone please share the code for this procedure with me?

Here is how the data look like:

| gene | sample1 | sample2 | sample3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TSPAN | -2.994 | -0.651 | 0.274 |
| LAP3 | 3.545 | -1.545 | 2.450 |
| ALS2 | -1.910 | -2.224 | -1.720 |

Thank you very much

Comment: @jgarces can you please help? Thank you

Comment: @Unheilig can you please help? Thank you